# React Native: Can someone help me make a custom alert?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

Hi can someone help me make the timeout alert box from the image below? It is the Refreshing Alert Box from Expo Mobile App, which appear when you save the code.[image]

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.arrow {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: '<';
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p><span>FirstTask</span><span class="arrow"></span></p>
      <p>09:09 - 09:09</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding, the alert is in the lower part of the screen and have the text of "Refreshing...". I don't know how to do it in React Native